# buffer java blocked to 1024?

Tags: java, android, buffer

I would like to stock more than 1024 bytes on my buffer. Actually I try to get value from `python` script.

33 values from my `python` script works :

`33*15(digits)*2(2 types of values)=990 bytes`.

If I try to send more than 33 values, it don't work. My program said 29 bytes received.

I think the problem is from the buffer. I tried to fix the buffer at 65536 but it change nothing. Did it exist any solution to stock like my buffer with more data ?

python code :

```
from pylab import*
from rtlsdr import*
from bluetooth import*
import sys

#configure device
sdr= RtlSdr()
sdr.sample_rate=double(sys.argv[3])
sdr.gain=double(sys.argv[2])
sdr.center_freq=double(sys.argv[1])
NFFT=34

#Bluetooth connection

server_sock=BluetoothSocket(RFCOMM)
server_sock.bind(("",PORT_ANY))
server_sock.listen(1)

port=server_sock.getsockname()[1]
uuid="94f39d29-7d6d-437d-973b-fba39e49d4ee"
client_sock,client_info=server_sock.accept()

while(1):
        samples=sdr.read_samples(256*1024)
        result=psd(samples,NFFT, Fs=sdr.sample_rate/1e6,    Fc=sdr.center_freq*1e6/1e6)
        tab_freq=(result[1]/1e6) 
        value_freq=str(tab_freq)[1:-1]
        value_list=[format(float(v), ".10f") for v in value_freq.split()]
        value_freq2= "\n".join(value_list)
        tab_pxx=result[0]
        value_pxx=str(tab_pxx)[1:-1]
        client_sock.send(value_freq2+'\n'+'\n'.join(value_pxx.split()))
```

java code :

```
public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1048576]; // 20 bits
            int bytes;
            String strRx = "";

            while (running) {
                try {
                    bytes = connectedInputStream.read(buffer);
                    final String strReceived_freq = new String(buffer,0, bytes);
                    final String strReceived_pxx = new String(buffer,(bytes/2)+1, bytes);
                    //final int samples_sdr=new Integer(buffer,0,bytes);
                    final String strByteCnt = String.valueOf(bytes) + " bytes received.\n";

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                                Pxx_value.setText(strReceived_pxx+"\n");    // get data PXX
                                freq_value.setText(strReceived_freq+"\n"); // get data freq

                            // plot value
                          /*  for (int i=0; i<nb_points; i++)
                            {
                                freq[i]=Double.parseDouble(strReceived_freq);
                                pxx[i]=Double.parseDouble(strReceived_pxx);
                                series.appendData(new DataPoint(freq[i],pxx[i]), true,500);
                            }*/

                        }});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What exactly is `connectedInputStream` connected to? and what exactly is the meaning of the computations in `new String(buffer,(bytes/2)+1, bytes)`?

Comment: With connectedInputStream, I get data by bluetooth from my Raspberry PI 3. I just edit my question to add my python script. `new String (buffer, 0, bytes/2)` get all freq value and `new String (buffer, (bytes/2)+1,bytes) get pxx value (dB/Hz)`

Comment: Well you can't get more from an input stream than what is available to be read. You could try adding a `BufferedInputStream`. but if you really need exactly say 2048 bytes at a time you need `DataInputStream.readFully()`.

Comment: oh ok so the problem is from the `InputStream` ? if I want to get more than 2048 bytes. For example : 15360 bytes ? How can I use `DataInputStream.readFully()` ?  `bytes=DataInputStream.readFully(buffer) ?`

Comment: It's all in the Javadoc. If `buffer` is 15360 bytes, `readFully()` will attempt to fill it before returning.

Comment: ok ! thanks for your help !

Comment: i tried to call DataInput stream but it change nothing

Answer (score -1):

Probably you lost to [`flush`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush--) your buffer (of the sender).

If you don't flush the buffer the output could be not written. From [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush--):

> Flushes this output stream and **forces any buffered output bytes to be written out**. The general contract of flush is that calling it is an indication that, if any bytes previously written have been buffered by the implementation of the output stream, such bytes should immediately be written to their intended destination.

While the answer is related to java code, any buffer works the same.

Try to add in your python code after the line:

```
client_sock.send(value_freq2+'\n'+'\n'.join(value_pxx.split()))
```

an explicit call to flush (I don't know exactly the syntax in python).

Comment: Calling `flush()` would make the problem worse, not better.

Comment: @EJP You are wrong. If not all bytes are received is possible that they are on the memory buffer (of the sender) and not yet sent. Is not possible to say that is not correct because the code is incomplete (at least it was when I answered)

Comment: Flushing causes smaller transmissions. Not flushing causes larger transmissions.

Comment: @EJP if the sender stay open (not explicitly call to close, for example because it is a stream of data) and flush is not invoked when necessary, is possible that the data will never pass from the sender to the receiver (if no new data will fill the buffer).

Comment: @EJP Flushing send data when you ask to to that. Not flushing retaining data in the buffer as long as possible. As a consequence if no new data are written in the buffer available data are never sent.

Comment: maybe you right, I'll try this because it change nothing always blocked at 990 bytes

Comment: @azzerty2017 check the length of your response using curl to be sure that at least the python part works well

Comment: @Davide Lorenzo MARINO the python part works well because I change the NFFT (number of points ==>change directly number of bytes) and I have no problem. The problem is from the java code

Comment: I do not understand how to flush and how flush can help to resolve my problem.